# duplicate check in array when edit the data in array

Tags: javascript

I push the data into an array. Before pushing, I check name already exists or not.

1. I checked whether the same name available in the array or not
2. If it exists alert throws " duplicate items"
3. If it is a new item, it will push into an array.

The below code has been working fine till now

But when I edit the existing item  address field, it will throw the duplicate alert items

```
this.arrayData = [{
    "name": "sachin",
    "address": "india"
}, {
    "name": "bin",
    "address": "us"
}, {
    "name": "gill",
    "address": "aus"
}]

var isInArray = this.arrayData.filter(c=>c.name === this.data.name);

if (isInArray.length > 0) {
    alert("dublicate items");
} else {
    this.saveItems(this.data);
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please give the complete object. Your code does not work. Also your array is invalid, you are missing quotes

Comment: You are checking if a given name value, is already existing in any of the current values. In case you are trying to _update_ an item, instead of creating a new one, _of course_ this will find the existing value as a "duplicate" (unless you are actually trying to change the name at the same time.) Only your "duplicate" is not an _actual_ duplicate, it is the very item you are trying to update here to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below solution to achieve the result.

```
 for(var i=0;i < this.arrayData.length;i++)
                 {       
                    if(i=== index) 
                    { 
                        if(this.arrayData[i].Name === this._data.Name )
                        { 
                            this.saveItems(this.data);  break;
                        }
                         
                        else if(this.arrayData[i].Name !== this._data.Name )
                        { 
                            var dataCheck = this.editDublicate(index);
                            if(!dataCheck) {
                                this.saveItems(this.data);   break;
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }  

    editDublicate(index)
{
    var dublicateData =false;
     for(var i=0;i < this.arrayData.length;i++)
     {
        if(this.arrayData[i].Name === this._data.Name &&  i !== index)
        { 
             alert("dublicate items");
            break;
        } 
     }
    return dublicateData;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want duplicates on array, just use Set, example code:

```js
let abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

function saveItems(newItem) {
  abc = [...abc, newItem]
  abc = [...new Set(abc)]
}

saveItems('d')
saveItems('d')
saveItems('e')

console.log(abc)

//output: (5) ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: His is more complicated as its objects not primitives.